# How to insert more than one call instruction using CreateCall in LLVM

Tags: llvm, instructions

I am running a module pass on my source code using llvm. For a certain instruction, I want 
to insert 2 or 3 instructions before the next instruction in the code. What I am currently doing is passing `Instruction->getNextNode()`  as the last argument to IRBuilder `CreateCall()` function to insert the instruction before next node in the code. How to insert more than one instruction before next node.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the instruction into some `Instruction*` and you keep passing the same instruction as the anchor to insert before, and it just works out. Consider this:

```
    foo
    bar
--> baz
```

`baz` is the last instruction. Now, you insert `abc` before `baz`:

```
    foo
    bar
    abc
--> baz
```

And now you insert `bcd` before `baz`:

```
    foo
    bar
    abc
    bcd
--> baz
```

Keep inserting before `baz` and you'll get the expected order for the inserted instructions. If you wanted to insert `bcd` *before* `abc` and not after, just pass it `abc` as the "instruction to insert before" at creation.